# ASP.NET Caching for all users

Tags: asp.net, http, caching, httpcontext

I'm wanting to cache some data in ASP.NET so that once a single cache is made, it is accesible to all users. Will HttpContext.Current.Cache do that, or is there another context's cache I need to be accessing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will HttpContext.Current.Cache do that

Yes, that's exactly what it is designed for: store data that will be available to all users of the application. You may also take a look at the [`@OutputCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx) directive which allows you to cache entire WebForms (aspx) or fragments (ascx) on the server or on the client contrary to `HttpContext.Current.Cache` which stores objects onto the server.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard of that one, but haven't really looked into it yet. I haven't had a need for it yet, but it seems like a pretty powerful load-time saver.